# How to Add Static Element(s) to Row at the Specified Location in JQuery DataTable

Tags: datatables

1、My English is very commonplace, so please pay attention to the problem instead of English grammar.Coding Without Borders.
------ From Google translation

**(Do not care the Chinese in code)**

2、I want add row at the specified location with Jquery DataTable .
like this example [jquery datatable add row](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html).

3、Now , I have a method like this

```js
var jRow = "<tr func='courier-new-tr'>" +
    "<td><span func='number'>1</span></td>" +
    "<td><input name='workId' required='true' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='账号'></td>" +
    "<td><input name='name' required='true' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='配送员姓名'></td>" +
    "<td><input name='phoneNum' maxlength='11' required='true' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='配送员手机'></td>" +
    "<td>" + setStateSelect() + "</td>" +
    "<td><label>" + new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd") + "</label></td>" +
    "<td>" +
    "<button class='btn btn-success' type='button' func='add-confirm'>确认</button>" +
    "<button style='margin-left: 1em;' class='btn btn-warning' type='button' func='add-cancel'>取消</button>" +
    "</td>" +
    "</tr>";
$("table#courier-table tbody").prepend(jRow);
```

4、the example in [3] has an effect like this
click the button "创建账号"(means to created a account),
table will add an row at the `index=0`(the first row) in `tbody`.
5、But I want to Listen the table.draw(),like this

```
$("#courier-table").on('draw.dt', function () {
     resetNumber();//to reset the row's No.
});
```

So , who can tell me ,how to use `DataTable.row().add()` to solve this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting is determined by the dataTable, so it only allows you to add rows at the end and then sorts it for you.

Just add it with `rows.add()` https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()

You have not shown where you apply your datatable, but the code will be something like this:

```
var dt = $("table#courier-table").api();
dt.rows.add(jRow);
```

Comment: bug i think it can't solve my question.Because I want add row in (index=0),that means add row to first row,but not to the last row.can you understand??

Comment: @ky91: And I am saying you do not need to add at entry 0 as dataTables will sort it anyway. You can always add it at the end *if* your table is sorted. If your dataTable is not sorted, then you have a problem. :)

Comment: this dt.rows.add(jRow),jRow maybe edit in it with static html like this "<input id='example'>",but also not add to the fast row .Uh, because my score less than 10, so I can not add a picture, maybe add a picture would be better. I try to go to Baidu plus wait outside the chain

Comment: @ky91: A picture would help. A better example of your code would also help.#

Comment: No, if the table has many rows of data, will lead the user must slide to the bottom of this page to view a new line, so bad user experience.

Comment: No... You do not understand. `dataTables` is in control of the sorting. If the new item belongs at the top, **based on the sorting**, it will appear at the top. It does not matter that the record was "added" by dataTables as it decides where to put it.

Comment: http://pan.baidu.com/s/1bnljlfx           this are three pictures in baidu .you can see the process from s1 to s3 .